# Insert NSManagedObject already instanced Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios

On apple doc, to insert a NSMananagedObject to Core Data, we need to do this :

```
- (void)insertObject
{
    NSMananagedObject *newObject = (UserInfo*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"myEntity" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [newObject setValue:@"aName" forKey:@"name"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
    }
}
```

But if my NSManagedObject is already instanced, how can I do to insert it on Core Data without re-Instancing with 'insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext' and copying my attributes ?

I would like something like this :

```
- (void)insertObject:(NSManagedObject*) newObject
{
    //[newObject insertForEntity:@"entityName" forContext:context];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Huh?  If it already exists you don't need to insert it again...just change it and call save

Comment: NO, new object I've just created but I'd like to use a 'manager class' which save in Core Data, that's why my object is instanced in a ViewController and I call the Manager Class for saving my object

Comment: You create it by calling the insertNewObject method.

Comment: I dont want to call it in my ViewController. Are there any other options to call it after without recreating my object ?

Comment: Not that I know of...creating an NSManagedObject in any other way usually results in warnings and errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `NSManagedObject` can **only** be created by inserting it into a context.  If you really want to have this in a manager class, you need separate functions to create it and then another one to save it.  (Well, you can have one that creates & saves, but then you will have to save it again anyway after you modify it.)

I would suggest something like this in your manager class:

```
- (UserInfo*)createNewUserInfoObject {
    return (UserInfo*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"myEntity"
                                                                            inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
}

- (BOOL)saveUserInfoObjects {
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to subclass your NSManagedObject and validate. That's what they are for is to add custom validations. No need for you to do any extra work and create a manager.

Here is some code to get you started.

```
- (BOOL) validateForInsert:(NSError *__autoreleasing*)error {

    /*! @abstract Validation for Inserting Records */

    BOOL bValidity    = [super validateForInsert:error];
    BOOL bUniqueness  = [self validateUniqueness:error];

    return ( bValidity && bUniqueness );
}
```

Note that the super is called first.